# tidyverse loads an earlier version of dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to use `tidyverse` and I keep having the same error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in
> loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.3 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
> Ejecución interrumpida

I have tried to uninstall `dplyr` and `tidyverse` and install it from their github repos. However, the error persists.

[image]

Comment: What version of R are you running? What's the output if you do `install.packages("dplyr")`?

Comment: One possibility is that there are two installation of `dplyr` found in the libraries. Look in each directory returned by `.libPaths()` and look for a `dplyr` directory; if you find multiple, that's a problem. (I find it less likely that this is the problem, more likely @MrFlick's suggestion will fix things.)

Comment: Indeed it seems there are two installations of dplyr! I have edited the question so that you see what happens when I call library("tidyverse")

Comment: The image you provided doesn't show any errors or warnings. Those are normal start up messages. It shows that dplyr 1.0.2 is loading. That doesn't match what you've shared in your error message. It's unclear to me what your question is at this point.